# Facebook Marketing API: What timezone the insights data used?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

If the adset insights data queried includes today, what is the `time since` of **today** insight data (such as ctr, roas), or what `timezone` insights data are used?

**Example code**

```
$adset = new FacebookAds\Object\AdSet($adset_id);
$params = [];
$params['time_increment'] = 1;
$params['time_range'] = [
    'since' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days'),
    'until' => date('Y-m-d')
];
$insightCursor = $adset->getInsights([
    'ctr',
    'website_purchase_roas'
], $parmas);

foreach ($insightCursor as $insight) {
    $date = $insight->{AdsInsightsFields::DATE_START};
    $ctr = $insight->{AdsInsightsFields::CTR};
    $roas = $insight->{AdsInsightsFields::WEBSITE_PURCHASE_ROAS};
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing how this is a coding question

Comment: @Ben Maybe the question should be rephrased: How to get the advertiser's timezone when pulling insights using hourly_stats_aggregated_by_advertiser_time_zone